# Many to Many relationship with ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am building a Code-First, Many-To-Many relationship between my ApplicationUser class and a Lesson class. When the model is created, Entity Framework builds the two tables and the intersecting pivot table. However, neither table seems to take in data from the pivot table (LessonApplicationUsers). Both List variables do not seem to hold either the list of Students or the list of Lessons. Both entities i'm trying to marry up already exist in the database

ApplicationUser class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public ClassLevel? ClassLevel { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public int? Height { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    public int? Weight { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Lessons = new List<Lesson>();
    }

    public ICollection<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
}
```

Lesson Class

```
public class Lesson
{
    [Key]
    public int LessonID { get; set; }
    public LessonType ClassType { get; set; }
    public ClassLevel? ClassLevel { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClassStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ClassEndDate { get; set; }
    public float ClassCost { get; set; }
    public int? InstructorID { get; set; }

    public Lesson()
    {
        Students = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    }

    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Students { get; set; }

    public enum LessonType {Group,Private}
}
```

My DBContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplyViewModel> Applications { get; set; }
```

And finally, the code i'm using to add in the pivot table data. This is activated when the user presses a button on the booking form.

```
public ActionResult BookUser()
    {
        //Gather required variables
        ApplicationUser user = db.Users.First(i => i.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        int classID = int.Parse(Request.Form["classID"]);

        using (db)
        {
            var editedLesson = db.Lessons.Single(s => s.LessonID == classID);
            db.Lessons.Attach(editedLesson);

            var editedUser = db.Users.Single(s => s.Id == user.Id);
            db.Users.Attach(editedUser);

            editedLesson.Students.Add(editedUser);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View("Index");
```

When I try and run it, when i press my book button, it runs through the code and executes. checking the database it has indeed inserted the key values into the pivot table. When i load the model of the lesson to view its details, the Student attribute has a count of 0. I've been at this for days and i've got the feeling i'm missing something kickself simple....but i've gone over it a dozen times and can't see what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: Mark your lists with `virtual` to enable lazy loading. Also is not required to initialize the lists `Lessons = new List<Lesson>();`.

Comment: **smacks head** before i saw this i had just tried that and it worked....i'm a numpty..

Answer (score 2):

Mark your lists with `virtual` to enable lazy loading. Also is not required to initialize the lists `Lessons = new List<Lesson>();`

Comment: It's possible to not use `virtual`, but then you must always eagerly/explicitly-load the collection if you need it. The traditional approach is to simply use virtual, but there's a lot of developers that explicitly choose not to allow lazy-loading. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx